# CocoaPods error on building project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a running project which is working fine with pods. I had to copy this project to develop version-2. Now when I try to build project, I encounter following issue in pod's code. I tried removing this specific pod but same type of errors were shown in different pod.

tried all of this: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html ,but it didn't help at all.

Being new to iOS development, I can't figure out, what I am doing wrong.

[image: When I am using IQKeyboardManager Pod shows this error]

Comment: I think you are using old version of Xcode!!

Comment: post your code on github ,if possible

Comment: I think you are using wrong version of pod, post your podfile line for IQKeyboardManager here and your swift version

Comment: Xcode version : 7.3 and swift 2.3. Will try to downgrade pod version.

Comment: Is you app target in Swift 2.2 then? If so, yes a short term solution is to downgrade the pod, long term you should update your app to Swift 3 and Xcode to the most recent version so that you can use the latest pods.

Comment: Issue resolved, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using the newer version of pod in older Xcode. So either you need to update your Xcode or downgrade your pod to the relevant version supporting Xcode. From image i can guess you might be using Xcode 7.2 or down and pod is in swift 2.3 or 3

Comment: can you share which Xcode are you using and Podfile?

Comment: It worked, Thank you. Actually at first I added versions to podfile but it was still installing newer version. Copying podfile.lock from previous project worked correctly.